# Regex to find whether given text not contain only email string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

I want to write a regex (java script) to match if the given text not contain only an email string.

for ex:

- abc -> should match
- abs@gmail.com sss -> should match
- abs@gmail.comsss -> should match
- aaa abs@gmail.com -> should match
- **abc@gmail.com -> should not match**

I wrote a regex using (?<!…) Negative lookbehind, to check whether given text does contain only email string or not as below. But I cant use + inside lookbehind expression and it gives `A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width` error.

regex:

`^.+(?<!([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.com))$`

explanation:

- `([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.com)` - regex to check email address.
- `^.+(?<!([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.com))$` - regex to check look behind of all non empty texts `(.+)`

Please give me an idea to resolve this issue...

Thanks

Comment: Just a heads up: That regular expression will not nearly catch all email addresses. E-mail addresses (and regular expressions to validate them) are quite complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to enclose the pattern of an email address in a negative lookahead assertion with anchors:

```
^(?![a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.com$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gutJB8/1

Note that your example of `aaaabs@gmail.com` in the question should not match even though you claim that it should.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... yes aaaabs@gmail.com should not match. it's a mistake. I updated the question... I will test this regex and will let you know... Thanks again or your reply.